# Can this code to loop through photos in a folder be optimised?

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, directory

I have written this code having not used PHP for 2 years now to loop through a folder of photos and write them to the page in alphabetical order. It is a fairly simple request but it took me the best part of 15 minutes to write.

```
if ($handle = opendir('photos')) {
  $count = 0;
  $list[] = array();
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      $list[$count] = $file;
      $count ++;
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
  asort($list);
  $sorted_list = array();
  $sorted_list = array_values($list);
  foreach ($sorted_list as $i => $value) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"photos/$sorted_list[$i]\" alt=\"$sorted_list[$i]\" title=\"\"></li>\n";
  }
}
```

Have I written it totally the wrong way? Are there ways I can improve the code? Any constructive feedback gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [scandir()](http://php.net/scandir) function, which will handle reading the directory as well as sorting the results.

```
$files = scandir('photos');
if ($files !== false) 
{
    foreach($files as $f) {
        if ($f == '..' || $f == '.') continue;      
        echo '<li><img src="photos/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title=""></li>'."\n";
    }
}
```

I edited it a bit for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$photos = glob('photos/*');
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"{$photo}" alt=\"{$photo}\" title=\"\"></li>\n";

}
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: yeah, it you know they are jpgs it's a good idea to use the extension. But they could in theory be any one of several photo formats.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `$count`. This will give you the same result

```
$list[] = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $list[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Replace sorting and displaying with just:

```
sort($list);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"photos/{$list[$i]}\" alt=\"{$list[$i]}\" title=\"\"></li>\n";
}
```

Comment: change $list[] = array() to $list = array(). also you want to use natsort(), instead of sort(). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
foreach ($sorted_list as $i => $value) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"photos/$sorted_list[$i]\" alt=\"$sorted_list[$i]\" title=\"\"></li>\n";
  }
```

with

```
foreach ($sorted_list as $value) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"photos/$value\" alt=\"$value\" title=\"\"></li>\n";
}
```

Then you don't need to call array_values(), because it doesn't matter that the array keys aren't in numeric order.

Answer (score 0):

A simplier way is using the [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function:

```
$dir = 'photos';
$files = array_diff( scandir($dir), array(".", "..") );
foreach ($files as $i => $value) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"photos/$value\" alt=\"$value\" title=\"\"></li>\n";
}
```

good luck!